# Is there a way to make the Dock in Mac OS X display your most frequently used apps?

Tags: mac, dock

I want this to be done automatically, so that I don't have to drag and drop anything myself.

Comment: You mean the `Apple menu`, `Recent items`, `Applications` list, but as Dock replacement?

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Yes.

Comment: I think your best bet is to check out DragThing. If that can't to this, there probably is no way.

Comment: Also, it's quite difficult to tell was a frequently used application is. Time running, time not hidden, time in foreground (but scrolling works for background-windows too!), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Warnaud about using a quick launch tool, but my recommendation is LaunchBar.  It's really amazing and can do a lot more than just launch apps.  Alfred is also capable of that with the Power Pack, so try both and see which one you like.

Answer (score 0):

Seems so: http://www.simplehelp.net/2008/04/28/how-to-add-a-recently-used-applications-stack-to-your-dock/
Good luck

Comment: Well, that's not quite the same - that's recently used, not most frequently used - but it's still useful - thanks!

Comment: Oups sorry. I don't see how to do this, nor don't find any solution :(

Comment: @Robin Now you contradict yourself. Mine (comment) is also "recently used", not "frequently used".

Comment: I personally use whether Alfred or Spotlight to launch app and they are stored in function of the usage

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Oops yes, sorry, you're right.